# Indexed access to XElement‘s child nodes

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml, xelement

I am parsing an XML document using LINQ to XML and `XDocument`. Is there a way for a `XElement`/`XContainer` to get a child node by the index (in document order)? So that I can get the `n`th node of the element?

I know I can probably do that by getting all the child nodes of that element and converting that `IEnumerable` to a `List`, but that already sounds like it would add a highly redundant overhead (as I am only interested in a *single* child node).

Is there something I missed in the documentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no indexed access to a child element using `XElement` or `XContainer`.  If you want indexed access, you have two options.

The first is to call the [`Elements`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342765.aspx) method on `XContainer` (which returns an [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) of `XElement` instances in document order) and then use the [`Skip` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) to skip over the elements to reach the particular child.

If you want to access the child elements often by index, then you should place them in a [`IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx) (which has indexed access), which is easy enough with the [`ToList` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx):

```
IList<XElement> indexedElements = element.Elements().ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, so there isn‘t an easier way :) – I have decided to refactor my data structure now a bit. Instead of working on the XML the whole time, I‘ll parse the XML once into a special data structure (stored in a list, so I have the random access) and use LINQ to work on those objects instead of XML then. That‘s probably better for my later work anyway.

Comment: @poke: That's probably better, given that the XML is only a representation of some other concept.  Usually, the storage mediums and the representation of the concepts don't always align, so it's always good to have transformations like this so you don't always bend around the limitations of what you are persisting to.

Answer (score 4):

what about Skip(n).Take(1) operators

Answer (score 2):

Maybe Take(topN) LINQ directive can help?
I'm making assumption based on some SQL related experience - you cannot get the row directly, but can take top n elements.

This can help if your list is huge and you don't encount last elements.